# Simple telnet chat server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

I was reading about sockets and found a nice exercise to try: a simple chat server that echoes input. This appears to be a common exercise and I have found several examples such as [chatserver5.py](http://homepages.ius.edu/jfdoyle/B438/HTML/chatserver4chatserver5Python.htm) and some [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3670127/266535) questions. The problem is I can only connect when using `telnet localhost 51234` and not `telnet 192.168.1.3 51234` (where 192.168.1.3 is the network IP of my "server"). Needless to say, I can't connect from another machine on my network. I get the following output:

```
Trying 192.168.1.3...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.3: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Here is my code:

```
import socket, threading

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 51234 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(4)
clients = [] #list of clients connected
lock = threading.Lock()


class chatServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, (socket,address)):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address= address

    def run(self):
        lock.acquire()
        clients.append(self)
        lock.release()
        print '%s:%s connected.' % self.address
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            for c in clients:
                c.socket.send(data)
        self.socket.close()
        print '%s:%s disconnected.' % self.address
        lock.acquire()
        clients.remove(self)
        lock.release()

while True: # wait for socket to connect
    # send socket to chatserver and start monitoring
    chatServer(s.accept()).start()
```

I have no experience with telnet or sockets. Why I can't connect remotely and how can I fix it so I can?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set `HOST = ''`, then you'll be able to connect from anywhere.  Right now, you're binding it to `127.0.0.1`, which is the same as `localhost`.

Comment: Wow that was easy. Telnet should be the same on any OS, correct? So no need for a client program; anyone can just telnet and type?

Comment: Yes, you can telnet from any OS to test this server.

Comment: I think Telnet is used for remote login, so is there a security risk running this on my machine?

Comment: Your server isn't a telnet server, so you're ok.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `HOST = '127.0.0.1'` with `HOST = '192.168.1.3'` or `HOST = ''`. This will bind you to your OUTGOING IP and not your internal localhost