# Python socket server for multiple connection handling

Tags: python, socketserver, python-sockets

Can some one suggest a good example for socket server which can handle multiple connections with threading from python. (Live connection (like server-client ping-pong) that will handle from threads)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810249/python-socket-multiple-clients looks relevant

Comment: Need a live connection.That will handle from threads.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `SocketServer` module you can create a server that handles multiple connections. Using [Asynchronous mixins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins) you can start new threads for each connection. There is a very good example in the Python documentation above.